# "Exemption" of a module in a university course

Tags: word-usage, word-request

If I have a degree in science and I then begin studying another degree in science, the new course might have some of the same units or modules (e.g. basic chemistry, or mathematics) as the old course. Because I've already completed those modules, I might be allowed to skip them.

For a person in this situation, would it be correct to say:

> This person got **exemption** of basic chemistry course.

I'm not sure whether this is correct usage of the word "exemption." If it isn't, what is an alternative?

Answer (score 4):

One word often used in this context is the verb ***waive***:

> Because you took it already, we can ***waive*** your basic chemistry course requirement.

If you're getting your second degree from a different institution from your first, then other words might apply. One is ***transfer***, which is when credit earned at one institution are applied toward degree requirements at another:

> We can ***transfer*** your chemistry credits, so you won't have to take that course again.

or even ***apply***:

> We can ***apply*** the chemistry credits you earned at your last school.

Finally, there is the phrasal verb ***test out***, which can be used when you need to pass a competency exam in lieu of taking the class again:

> If you score high enough, you can ***test out*** of the chemistry course.

Comment: You can also be "credited for" classes already taken.

Answer (score 3):

Before I answer, your example sentence isn't grammatical English. It should be:

> This person got **an** exemption **from the** basic chemistry course.

However, I don't think a native speaker would use "exemption" here. To be exempt from something, that something needs to be a requirement, which the chemistry course isn't. The requirement in this case would be *taking* the course. I think it would also be more natural to use the verb *to exempt* in this context:

> This person **was exempted** from taking the basic chemistry course.

This sentence sounds more natural, but still isn't what I would expect a native speaker to say. I don't think there's a good reason for this, other than there being more specific terms used in this context.

[J.R.'s answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/119353/37589) provides some good examples of what a native speaker might say:

> - Because you took it already, we can **waive** your basic chemistry course
>     requirement.
> - We can **transfer** your chemistry credits, so you won't have to take that
>     course again.
> - We can **apply** the chemistry credits you earned at your last 
>     school.<sup>‡</sup>
> - If you score high enough, you can **test out** of the chemistry course.

<sup><sup>‡</sup> Note that use of "school" to describe a university (or college) is primarily an American usage. In British English, it would only be referred to as a university, and it would only ever be a university which could
grant a degree.</sup>

There is an exception to the rule, however. If the module was not optional for students who hadn't already taken it, a lecturer or professor might use "exempt" when describing the module:

> This module is mandatory. Students who have already **gained** the module
>   are **exempt**.